# php prevent form resubmission using sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, form-submit, forms

So I am trying to prevent form resubmission using sessions 
and this is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['unid']))
{
    if ($_GET['unid']==$_SESSION["uid"])
    {
        echo "Form is Submited do something";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no you can't do that";
    }
}
$unid = md5(uniqid());
$_SESSION["uid"] = $unid;
?>
<form method="GET">
    <input name="name" value="test">
    <input name="unid" value="<?php echo $unid;?>">
<input type="submit">
```

and it works ...but if the user opens another tab then it will break so how can I fix it ?

Comment: what exactly does `it will break` mean? Does that mean that the form can be submitted again (with an existing value for $unid)? What should happen if we detect there is a `unid` value in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: When you have two tabs for the same page one of them will submit the form and the other page will not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but may be assigning a new global session variable will work, say `$_SESSION['checkSub']`. So once the form is submitted, set it to `1` or `true` and only let form submission if it isn't `1` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the `unid` is set in the session before generating a new unique id. See updated code below:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['unid']))
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['unid']) && $_GET['unid']==$_SESSION['unid'])
        {
            //form has been submitted with matching unid - process it as needed
            unset($_SESSION['unid']);
        }
        else
        {
            // Form was resubmitted or some other logic error
        }
    }
    $unid = ''; //declare here for good scope
    if (isset($_SESSION["unid"])) {
            $unid = $_SESSION["unid"];
    }
    else {
            $unid = md5(uniqid());
            $_SESSION["unid"] = $unid;
    }
    ?>
    <form method="GET">
        <input name="name" value="test">
        <input name="unid" value="<?php echo $unid;?>">
    <input type="submit">
```

Comment: I can tell that your code is better but the problem is not solved yet ..

Comment: [@Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/145976/charlie) [added that `unset()` call](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40098410/revisions) - without that, the forms will both submit (in first and second tabs) with the same unid value

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using form method `GET`, try to use `POST`. It will work for you. The  `$_POST` array will only have data in it when form is submitted, so you should not have to use the session to know whether form is submitted or not.